# Show that if $f \in R$, $f \ne 0$, then $f$ is a unit or a zero-divisor.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Consider the commutative ring $R=\{f \mid f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R\}$ with addition defined as $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ and multiplication $(fg)(x)=f(x)g(x)$. Show that if $f \in R$, $f \ne 0$, then $f$ is a unit or a zero-divisor.

Suppose that  $f$ is not a zero-divisor. Then $\forall g \in R$ non-zero we have that  $fg\ne 0$.

What I need to show now is that there exists $h \in R$ such that $fh=1$ i.e. $f(x)h(x)=1$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$. If $h=1/f$, then $fh=1$ for all $x \in R$, but how can I be sure that $1/f$ exists?

Comment: $1/f$ exists only when $f$ is not zero in all points. You need to show that if $f(x)=0$ for some $x$, then $f$ is a zero-divisor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that if $f(x)=0$ for any single $x$, then $f$ becomes a nonzero zero divisor.

So we know if $f$ is nonzero and isn't a zero divisor, then $f(x)\neq 0$ for every $x$. Since $\mathbb R$ is a field $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ exists, then, for all $x$.